# React Drop down menu disappears when moving the cursor

Tags: reactjs

I have built a react drop down menu . It appears when I bring my mouse over but disappears as soon I move cursor down to click on one of the menu items.
Please can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

This is the link [current behavior video](https://filebin.net/dkzye6g27fxnzcss) that displays the behavior I am experiencing:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext({
  authenticated: false, profile: null
});

export const HeaderContext = createContext('');


export function AccountMenu(props){

const [userState, setUserState] = useContext(UserContext);
const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState(false);
const [renderMSLogin, setMSLogin] = useState(false);

function onRoleClick(role){
    setUserState({
      ...userState,
      currentRole: role //displays user's current role on the top right corner
    });
  }


return(
    <React.Fragment>
    <div className='account-menu'
        onMouseEnter={() => setMouseOver(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setMouseOver(false)}>
          
      
      <div className='list-item title'>{'Roles'}</div>
      {profile.roles.map((role, i)=>(
        <div key={role + i} className='list-item role' 
          onClick={()=>onRoleClick(role)}>
          {'-'} {role._id}
        </div>
      ))}

        

      <a href='/api/auth/logout' className='list-item logout'
          onClick={()=>setMSLogin(true)} >logout</a>

    </div>
 
      {renderMSLogin ? <MSLogin/> : null  }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. I had to change how I change the state of mouseOver.

Originally I had :

```
<div className='account-menu'
        onMouseEnter={() => setMouseOver(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setMouseOver(false)}>
```

The change I had to make :

```
<div className='account-menu'
        onMouseEnter={() => setMouseOver(!mouseOver)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setMouseOver(!mouseOver)}>
```